# When subquery behind SELECT can not be removed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Correlated subqueries are considered to be a [bad habit](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-code-smells/#using-correlated-subqueries-instead-of-a-join). I believe that any SQL command with a subquery between `SELECT` and `FROM` (lets call it *SELECT subquery*) can be rewritten into a SQL without any. For example query like this

```
select *,
(
  select sum(t2.sales)
  from your_table t2
  where t2.dates
         between t1.dates - interval '3' day and 
                 t1.dates and 
       t2.id = t1.id
) running_sales
from your_table t1
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=388ca45abc2cdbefb91caf36a7d6c2a4)

can be rewritten into the following one

```
 select dd.id, dd.dates, dd.sales, sum(d.sales) running_sales
 from your_table dd
 join your_table d on d.dates
     between (dd.dates - interval '3' day) and 
              dd.dates and 
     dd.id = d.id
 group by dd.id, dd.dates, dd.sales
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=02ea90d694a5a17783420ba422fc91d1)

The problems may occur when there is more than one SELECT subquery, however, even in those case, it is possible to rewrite them into a subquery behind `FROM` and then perform a `LEFT JOIN` in the following spirit

```
select *,
(
  select sum(sales)
  from dat dd
  where dd.dates
         between (d.dates - interval '3' day) and d.dates and 
         dd.id = d.id
) running_sales,
(
  select sum(sales)
  from dat dd
  where dd.id = d.id
) total_sales
from dat d
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6cceeb439fe26b230747554c8a49807a)

can be rewritten into the following one

```
select d.*,
   t_running.running_sales,
   t_total.total_sales
from dat d
left join (
  select dd.id, dd.dates, sum(d.sales) running_sales
  from dat dd
  join dat d on d.dates
          between (dd.dates - interval '3' day) and 
                   dd.dates and 
          dd.id = d.id
  group by dd.id, dd.dates
) t_running on d.id = t_running.id and d.dates = t_running.dates
left join (
  select d.id, sum(d.sales) total_sales
  from dat d
  group by d.id    
) t_total on t_total.id = d.id
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=077bfcf31ab5b37f069a3293e45b9bf5)

Could you please provide me an example where it is **not** possible to get rid of the SELECT subquery? Please be so kind and add also a working example link (e.g. [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/), or [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)) to make the potential disscussion is easier, thanks!

Comment: I really have no idea if this is on topic for SE?...In any case, I'd give the answer of 'no', subqueries in the select statement can always be expressed in a better manner.

Comment: I agree, this is off topic. That said, sometimes for clarity sake, it is appropriate to use sub queries. My main database is Oracle, not SQL*Server as in your tag, butI have written queries both ways on Oracle and have received identical explain plans, so it made no difference performance wise.

Comment: @BrianLeach ok and why it is considered to be a bad habit then? I've read such opinion in more places than in the link provided.

Comment: They can always be trivially swapped into an outer apply. Sub queries with top N can’t be rewritten as a join though without radically rewriting to use different constructs such as row number.

Comment: I agree that it is commonly a bad idea.  The only place where I have seen it used in a valid fashion was in a case where data was being retrieved from a CRM database which used row level security on the filtered view.  Retrieving the lookup data in a select subquery reduced the number of records for which security needed to be checked and significantly improved performance.  I do however still cringe whenever I look at one of the queries.

Comment: @RadimBača - it is a bad habit, for SQL Server at least, because without any optimisation (query plan optimisation) `SELECT` sub-query will be executed once for every row returned by the parent `SELECT`, meaning that for 100 rows returned you will get 100 tables / index seeks/scans. Historically SQL Server has been bad at optimising (moving them to `FROM` part) these kinds of queries. This is in part because sub-query will fail if it returns more than 1 row and SQL Server has no way to know in advance if more than 1 row may be returned unless unique indexes or `TOP 1` constructs are used.

Comment: Continued... In my experience, it is getting better now days and they no longer "as bad" a practise as they used to be but can still hurt performance in unexpected ways.

Comment: @RadimBača I can't answer for why others find it to be a bad habit. Having minimal experience in SQL*Server, perhaps the optimizer doesn't do well with sub-queries, I don't know. I do know that people often take a rule of thumb and turn it into an absolute. On small datasets, it really doesn't matter, I frequently see retrieval times less than parse times. On large data sets, test. If you get a bad explain plan, re-write the query to use a join instead.

Comment: The `code smell` is usually (in my experience) associated with sheer volume of correlated subqueries within the select clause to the extent that, when executed, such a query would cause a citywide black-out (well, *maybe not quite*). Correlated subqueries handled through an apply operator (or lateral joins) are usually well optimized now (like the "top n" example cited above) so they may even be of benefit when used through the from clause. As said by @MartinSmith many such queries are very simply moved into an outer/cross apply or lateral join depending on db/version.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is for a multiple-choice test (or something like that) :) , it is not possible to get rid of subquery for `EXISTS` clause.

An other similar answeris for `IN (subquery)` for different level of aggregation to avoid cartesian product.

(same comment by the way : correlated subqueries are not considered everytime to be a bad habit, it depends of optimization, structure, etc....

The `WITH` is a sort of use of correlated subqueries... and it's very practical for complex queries.  )